# Default value for peewee DoubleField doesn't get reflected in MySQL db

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-peewee

Use case: Want to store `0.0` as default value while no value is passed for a `pewee`'s `DoubleField`. I wrote following code but didn't work for me.

```
class MyRelation(peewee.Model):
    id = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    percentage = peewee.DoubleField(default=0.0)
```

Here is an api

```
@api_blueprint.route('/add_data', methods=['POST'])
@http_header
def add_data():
    try:
        incoming = json.loads(request.data)
        data = MyRelation(percentage=incoming["percentage"])
        data.save()

        return success_response(201,"Data has been inserted :)")

    except Exception as e:
        log(str(e))
        return raise_error(500, str(e))
```

which logs following error

```
10-05-17 05:24:51 Line:199  Message: Error in add_data(),views.api: (1048, "Column 'percentage' cannot be null")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is only enforced on the Python side -- so if you're expecting the server to enforce the default you'll need to use a constraint:

```
percentage = peewee.DoubleField(constraints=[SQL('DEFAULT 0.0')])
```

Docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#default-field-values

Comment: What's `SQL` here? Can't understand this `[SQL('DEFAULT 0.0')]` here.

Comment: `from peewee import SQL` -- it is used to express a SQL literal with peewee.

Comment: If definitely modifies MySQL structure but still throws this error. @coleifer